# Module unittest Kohana error, how to use?

Tags: unit-testing, kohana

I am trying times longer run it has several errors. Someone
has any tutorial or some way to make it work. Tested
several tutorials and I could not.
vlw staff

I already placed the php unittest unit in the directory.
the error is as follows:

Fatal error: main() [function.require]: Failed opening required
'PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp
\www\doeseulixo\branches\module_unittest\modules\unittest\PHPUnit
\Framework.php on line 0

Answer (score 1):

See [Installing PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html).

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit should be installed with the 'pear' utility rather than downloaded manually. Kohana needs access to more than one class of the library.